# How to join two TIFF files populated using memory-mapped IO

Tags: python, numpy, tiff, numpy-ndarray, memory-mapped-files

I'm trying to write a python function which will output a single TIFF file after combining multiple TIFF files. I have a folder with a large amount of TIFF files and I'm trying to join each of the TIFF files into a single file. I have to load the data as numpy array and should also be populating using memory-mapped IO.

Comment: How should the images be combined? Stacked? Stitched?

Comment: And furthermore, what have you tried so far and what are the problems you encountered?

Comment: The images should be stacked, I have been using the Tifffile library with memmap to create an empty TIFF file, but I am a little bit confused on how to join all the files into a single one. Unfortunately I'm not very used to the working with this type of data so I'm having trouble trying to combine everything together.

Comment: I'm usually doing that by creating a 3d numpy array with the z-axis being the number of images and slice every image in one z-Layer. Save the result as tiff and you're done.

Comment: Do you have an example of how to do that? Sorry I'm just a little lost on the exact syntax of how to iterate through each TIFF file and then combining them all together into the array.

Comment: Stack vertically... `tallTIFF = np.vstack((TIFF1,TIFF2,TIFF3))` or horizontally... `wideTIFF = np.hstack((TIFF1, TIFF2, TIFF3))`

Answer (score 0):

Untested example, that should give you an idea:

```
from pathlib import Path
import numpy as np
import tifffile

my_path = Path(r'path/to/tiffs')
output = Path('output.tiff')

tiffs = list(my_path.glob('*.tiff'))

x,y = (512,512) # either hardcode or read from first tiff

output = np.zeros((len(tiffs), x, y))

for i, image in enumerate(tiffs):
    a = tifffile.imread(image.open(mode = 'rb'))
    output[i, :, : ] = a

tifffile.imsave(output.open(mode='wb'), output)
```

Comment: Hi thanks that helped a lot! I just have a problem with saving the tiff file, as I'm getting errno 22, any ideas on that?

Comment: In which line? It usually means, the file does not exist or you don't have permission to write.